# Arraylist that sometimes contain data, and sometimes not

Tags: android, android-volley

A newbie for here.

I'm working in an app with Android and a strange thing happens to me with a While loop. I make a series of requests to the database with volley library and it returns the data well. No problem.

The problem, i think, is in the last function DameColorPlato(), because sometimes the code accesses the while loop and it passes through it well, but sometimes it does not, and it returns the default value of the CC variable (#000000) and it does not show me well the colors of the text.

This is my code (In summary):

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

     Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
     id_usuario = datos.getString("id_usuario");
     idCentro = datos.getString("id_centro");
     fecha_actual = datos.getString("fechaActual");
     fecha_actual_SQL = datos.getString("fechaActualSQL");


         plato1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         plato2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);



         ObtPlatos_volley(idCentro, fecha_actual_SQL);

         ObtColores_volley();


     public void ObtPlatos_volley(final String id_centro, final String fecha_actual_SQL){


         String url = "http://neton.es/WS_neton/menu_dia.php?id_centro="+id_centro+"&fecha_actual_SQL="+fecha_actual_SQL;

         StringRequest eventfulRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                 new Response.Listener<String>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(String response) {
                         try {

                             JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                             for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                                 platouno = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("plato1");
                                 platodos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("plato2");



                                 platounoColor = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("tipo1");
                                 platodosColor = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("tipo2");


                             }


                                 plato1.setText(platouno);

                                 String co1 = DameColorPlato(CodTipoPlato, ColorLetra, platounoColor);

                                 plato1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(co1));



                                 plato2.setText(platodos);

                                 String co2 = DameColorPlato(CodTipoPlato, ColorLetra, platodosColor);

                                 plato2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(co2));



                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();

                         }
                     }
                 },
                 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         Log.e("Error: ", error.toString());
                     }
                 });

         VolleySingleton.getInstance(this)
                 .addToRequestQueue(eventfulRequest);
     }



     public void ObtColores_volley(){

         String url = "http://neton.es/WS_neton/color_platos.php";

         StringRequest eventfulRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                 new Response.Listener<String>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(String response) {
                         try {

                             int cod_color_letra;
                             String color_letra;


                             JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                             for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                 cod_color_letra = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("cod_tipoplato");
                                 color_letra = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("color");

                                 CodTipoPlato.add(cod_color_letra);
                                 ColorLetra.add(color_letra);
                             }

                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();

                         }
                     }
                 },
                 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         Log.e("Error: ", error.toString());
                     }
                 });

         VolleySingleton.getInstance(this)
                 .addToRequestQueue(eventfulRequest);
     }



     public String DameColorPlato(ArrayList<Integer> CodColorL, ArrayList<String> ColorL, int tipoplato){

         String CC="#000000";
         int i=0;
         boolean encontrado=false;


     while (i < CodColorL.size() && !encontrado) {

         if (tipoplato == CodColorL.get(i)) {

             CC = ColorL.get(i);

             encontrado = true;

         }else {
             i++;
         }

     }
         return CC;
     } 
}
```

With a Toast I have found that ArrayList CodColorL and ArrayList ColorL variables sometimes come with values, and sometimes they come empty. But i cannot found the error.

Thanks in advance!

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Your code will never work reliably because you are doing two different requests and hoping one ends up before the other. This is called a race condition. At times, your `ObtPlatos_volley` function finishes before `ObtPlatos_volley` finds the colors and which is why you are getting empty colors

Comment: Thanks for you advance, Napster. I'm too newbie for understand what happen, but does that mean that I can not make two requests to the databases in the same class?

Comment: Yes you can do that. The only thing is that those volley requests are async so they run on different threads and either of those can finish before or after. So what you need to do is make sure that `ObtPlatos_volley` runs after `ObtColores_volley` has finished

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Napster for your help. Your advice has helped me a lot to learn about this concept. Thank you again!

Comment: No worries! If the answer helped you then please accept it so if anyone else looks at this question can get some help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained out in the comments, for anyone else looking at this question, the reason why OP was seeing the issue of unreliable data is because they are making two `Volley` requests and expecting one to finish before implicitly.

By default, Volley requests are run in a queue but are `Asynchronous` which means that the requests won't necessarily finish in the order that they were started in the queue. Since OP's one request is dependent on the data from the other the correct way to do this is by synchronously running the requests. This can be done in a few ways such as using a callback from the first request or through starting the second request in the `onResponse` block of the first one.

One more way to achieve the same is to create your own architecture of running requests where you have a way to run all the requests on a single thread but that is over optimizing for this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This helped me to understand the Asynchronous concept and solve my problem.